# How to update a column with multiple rows concatenated each other

Tags: mysql, sql, sas

I'm working on SAS platform and I have a table of my object and another table save comments against that object. One object may have multiple comments. as

```
object
 ID | Name | Other Attributes 
  1    obj       ...  

Comment
ID | Comment | object_ID | type
 1    first       1        custom
 2    Second      1        custom
```

I want to create a table of cast_comm who has comma separated comments in a single row as

```
proc sql noprint;
create table cast_comm as
select distinct O.ID,C.Comment
from Comments as C, Object as O
where O.ID = C.Object_ID
and C.type = "custom"
quit;
```

I want to have table as

```
cast_comm
ID | Comments
 1    First, Second
```

guys what approach should I use to do it? Appreciate your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS PROC SQL - Concatenate variable values into a single value by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434677/sas-proc-sql-concatenate-variable-values-into-a-single-value-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no group concat to use in proc sql;
you can use a datastep after the join:

```
data cast_comm_concat;
    set cast_comm;
by id; /*make sure it's sorted*/
length comments $ 1000 ;
retain comments;

if (first.id) then do;
   comments="";
end;

comments=catx(",",comments,comment);

if last.id then do;
    output;
end;

run;
```

Comment: `catx` already [strips blanks](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0p7wxtk0hvn83n1pveisbcp2ae9.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en), why the extra `strip`?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).
Try this in MySQL:

```
create table cast_comm
select distinct o.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.Comment)
from object o
left join Comment c on c.object_ID =  o.id;
```

Comment: function group contact could not be located

Comment: This question has the `sas` tag. The associated sql implementation is rather limited by modern standards and does not include this function. This syntax might work in a pass-through query to another dbms, but not within sas itself.